# React Native app using webview for loading html, js and css file getting slow

Tags: ios, react-native, webview

I have developed a React Native IOS app  loading .html, .javascript and .css files into web-view for content to get displayed. I am able to launch the content and play, but the issue is app performance is getting slow and app getting stuck when I am playing the content in web-view after some time. I am unable to predict the issue, can anyone say what might be the issue?